# Does Kibana take data from ElasticSearch or LogStash directly?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

This might be quite a dumb question but I couldn't find the explanation in any architectural overview of the ELK stack.

When data are displayed in real time, does Kibana use LogStash directly or Kibana get the information from ElasticSearch after it's been put there by LogStash?

I'm asking this because I want to do some custom query on the fly, so that Kibana results become optimized with time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kibana takes data from ElasticSearch.

Comment: Do you also happen to know what it uses to pull that data? (i.e. queries or something else)

Comment: Kibana 3 runs only in your browser and uses queries (you can open network tab in developer mode in your browser to see the exact queries). Kibana 4 has server side component so I'm not 100% sure if it uses HTTP API.

Answer (score 1):

As Kresimir Nesek told you, Kibana takes data from Elasticsearch search using the REST API. Data are previously parsed and indexed by logstash (if you use it) and sent to elasticsearch for storing.

Both, Kibana 3 and 4, use the REST API or Elasticsearch to query. See the official [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html) for more information.

You might probably be interesteed in Elasticsearch node/cluster management, I recommend you [this](http://www.elastichq.org/) management/monitoring interface for Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I'll take this chance to pose yet another question: Do you know of a project/tool for automatically detecting patterns in ElasticSearch Data? I'm looking for a way to take periodic streams of data, analyse them and automatically detect patterns and then refine them with user aid.

Comment: In my mind, the only thing Elasticsearch does is storing and searching your data. What you are speaking about is "analysing" data and your data have to be analysed before coming to Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch just allows you to search your analysed data efficiently. So, you might be able to do what you want with logstash or another equivalent software. If you absolutly want automation in the process, you might be interested by "machine learning", but I can not give any advice to you regarding this topic.

Comment: I see. From what I've been reading, the approach would be using Hadoop which opens up a lot of possibilities in terms of conducting machine learning and doing the "sought after" pattern discovery that I so desperately need.